# Protect entity from cascade delete in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Simple question: does anyone have any ideas how to protect some entity from being deleted via `CascadeType.ALL` in `hibernate` **in runtime** (may be with throwing a runtime exception)?

Say, we have some entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO_ENTITY")
public class FooEntity {
     ...
}
```

And I want to protect it from accidental wrong mapping, like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_OTHER_FOO_ENTITY")
public class SomeOtherFooEntity {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ENTITY_ID")
    private FooEntity fooEntity;
}
```

So, it should be possible to delete some entity of type `FooEntity` via `session.delete(fooEntityObj)`, but it must be disabled ability to delete it via cascade removal (`session.delete(someOtherFooEntityObj)`).

**ATTENTION**: For those who read my question inattentive or think that I do not understand what am I asking:

1) I **can not remove** `CascadeType.ALL`. The question is: who programming avoid and protect from this?

2) Unit tests is not the way, I'm looking for **runtime** solution.

Comment: Flexibility comes with responsibility, meaning that you should use every feature with care. Don't you control your entire code?

Comment: Indeed I have very huge project and not only somebody else, but also me, could accidental add such mapping and destroy valuable data in such way.

Comment: In any way, guys, I'm interesting in programming way how to protect from such situation.

Comment: This is one of the reasons we all write unit tests. You can write a unit test for this

Comment: @SteveC Great! How do you imagine such unit test? If I will remember to test it, I will never create such mapping. Also others. This is not the way.

Comment: If you practice [Test Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) you will not forget!

Comment: @SteveC please post that as an answer, because that is definitely a solution (if not the single one), that I want to upvote :).

Comment: @Andremoniy do use you tests at all? Do you use maven? Maven will fail by default generating the assembly (jar, war or ear) if any tests fail. If you still generate your JAR from Eclipse, I sincerely recommend to switch to Maven (or better Gradel).

Comment: @SteveC If you don't know that something exists, how can you write a test (unit or any other) for it? Could you please post that solution as an answer if you think that it solves the OP's issue?

Comment: Thanks all, guys, but I'm looking for `runtime` protection. Not compile-time and not build-time.

Comment: Where are you going to dictate which relationships should throw a runtime exception for CascadeType.ALL?  Or do you never want CascadeType.ALL to be valid?

Comment: Pfff... I just want to be sure, that even if some idiot (like me) adds such type of cascading, this will not destroy data of particular type of entity when deleting related entities. Best practice, I think, would be some special JPA annotation on desired entity, something like `@DisableCascadeRemoval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways this can be done is to programmatically inspect Hibernate mapping meta-data and to check whether any delete operation (`ALL`, `REMOVE`, `orphanRemoval`) cascades to the protected entity from any other entity; something like:

```
String protectedEntityName = FooEntity.class.getName();
SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) session.getSessionFactory();

for (EntityPersister entityPersister : sessionFactory.getEntityPersisters().values()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entityPersister.getPropertyTypes().length; i++) {
        Type type = entityPersister.getPropertyTypes()[i];
        EntityType entityType = null;
        if (type.isCollectionType()) {
            CollectionType collectionType = (CollectionType) type;
            Type elementType = sessionFactory.getCollectionPersister(collectionType.getRole()).getElementType();
            if (elementType.isEntityType()) {
                entityType = (EntityType) elementType; 
            }
        } else if (type.isEntityType()) {
            entityType = (EntityType) type;
        }
        if (entityType != null && entityType.getName().equals(protectedEntityName)) {
            if (entityPersister.getPropertyCascadeStyles()[i].doCascade(CascadingAction.DELETE)) {
                // Exception can be thrown from here.
                System.out.println("Found! Class: " + entityPersister.getEntityName() + "; property: " + entityPersister.getPropertyNames()[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This validation can be performed on server startup or in an integration test.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to modify the defined behavior of Hibernate; it just acts as a reminder that you forgot not to cascade deletion to the `FooEntity`.

Regarding the tests, yes, I know that the OP explicitly said that tests are not an acceptable solution for this use case (and I personally agree with it in general). But these kinds of automatic tests may be useful because you write them and forget about them; you don't have to update the tests whenever you add a new mapping or modify an existing one (which defeats the purpose of the tests because you may forget or oversee to adopt the tests for each possible use case).

Answer (score 1):

For starters I think you do understand what you're asking, you've just settled on a specific solution that many people, myself included, are questioning.  It's not inattentiveness...it's trying to solve your actual problem.

If you really want to stop the `CascadeType.ALL` value on annotations from having its documented effect, instead of verifying that `CascadeType.ALL` is not used where it shouldn't be (and validating those expectations via unit tests), then extend the `DefaultDeleteEventListener` and override the deleteEntity method to always pass false to the super implementation for the `isCascadeDeleteEnabled` flag.

If you want a solution that has some semblance of standard, expected behavior, then define relationship that should do cascading deletes at the schema level, and establish best practices to only use the `CascadeType`s that you care about in your code.  Maybe that's PERSIST and MERGE, maybe you're using save and update functionality of session factory and so you need to use the Hibernate-specific `@CascadeType` annotation .

Comment: First of all I definitely understand what I'm asking. Secondly your answer in part of `DefaultDeleteEventListener ` much more closer to what I'm looking for, may be even it is a solution.

Comment: then there's also no reason why you can't add your own @DisableCascadeRemoval and check it in your custom listener to decide where to call super with true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove `cascade` attribute from `@ManyToOne` annotation if you don't want to cascade changes to objects associated with the one that is really changed?

Comment: Thanks captain obvious, but It seems you read my question very inattentive

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to catch any kind of programming error is to write unit tests.

If you practice [Test Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) you will minimise the chances of "forgetting" to do it.

Comment: What SteveC actually means is to create a test in which all kind of entities with `ManyToOne` relationships to the `FooEntity` are persisted and then deleted. The test should fail if the a certain `fooEntity` instance will also be deleted.

Comment: TDD is the great Utopia and it is not appropriate for startup or small-team projects.

Comment: BTW it seems you very poorly understand how this test could be written. Even if man who added undesired cascade type will write some test, he will not care about safety of related data of `FooEntity` type. And all other tests will not be able to control this behavior.

Comment: Downvoting not because I think that automatic tests are bad when they make sense, but because no helpful example regarding the question is presented in the answer.