# hibernate jpa, is there a simple way to get the dependent entity of a entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to get dependent on other entities of a entity,for example:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

I get the entity who dependent on User, it is Role.I can parse @ManyToMany to get it,but if use xml configuration,I can not simply do that, so I would like to know if hibernate provides the API that can help me do this? thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `EntityPersister`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31544714/4754790) is an example of using it to obtain mapping meta-data; it should be relatively easy to obtain information about types of associated entities as well.

Comment: @Dragan Bozanovic i read `EntityPersister`,it also useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JPA you can get all the information with the Metamodel, for example:

```
entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(User.class).getCollection("roles");
```

Hibernate also provides some useful methods on the SessionFactory:

```
hibernateSession.getSessionFactory().
    getClassMetadata(User.class).getPropertyType("roles") ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but I have a solution (Mathias' approach using Metamodel is right, but his answer requires one to know about the dependency beforehand, which misses the point of the question)

```
        List<Class<?>> dependentEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManager.getMetamodel()
            .getEntities()) {
            boolean isDependent = entity.getDeclaredAttributes()
                .stream()
                .map(Attribute::getJavaType)
                .anyMatch(isEqual(User.class));
            if (isDependent) {
                dependentEntities.add(entity.getJavaType());
            }
        }
```